# Yii2 validation rule for select field

Tags: forms, yii2, yii2-validation

I have a model, for example SomeForm. There is a field. This field contains an array of selected options. Is it possible to write a rule for this field to check how many items were selected? I need to write a condition, that user has to check minimum 2 options and maximum 5.

I tried something like this, but it doesn't work (the form can be submitted if at least one option is selected)

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['ingredients'], 'required'],
        ['ingredients', 'checkIsArray']
    ];
}
public function checkIsArray($attribute, $params)
{
    if (empty($this->ingredients)) {
        $this->addError($attribute, "config cannot be empty");
    }
    elseif (count($this->ingredients)>5) {
        $this->addError($attribute, "Choose more");
    }
    elseif (count($params)<2) {
        $this->addError($attribute, "Choose less");
    }
}
```

Comment: just a question are you using `advanced-app` or `basic` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but you have a wrong assignment of variable i.e `$params` in the last condition `elseif (count($params)<2)` you are counting `$params` instead of the `$this->ingredients` array. And you do not need to have the first check, adding the attribute to the required rule is enough to check if it is empty when submitted.

change the validation function to

```
public function checkIsArray( $attribute , $params ) {

    if ( count ( $this->ingredients ) > 5 ) {
        $this->addError ( $attribute , "Choose No more than 5" );
    } elseif ( count ( $this->ingredients ) < 2 ) {
        $this->addError ( $attribute , "Choose No less than 2" );
    }
}
```

I just tested it before posting with the **`kartik\Select2`** multiselect and it works just fine, but if it still reacts the same you need to add the **`controller/action`** code hope it helps you out.